# Switch case in order to check if string contains a substring

Tags: javascript

I have a string and want to check if there is a substring with switch/case. The fnstringCheck returns `true` for example if the fnstring is `dies_ist_ein_test_diagnosen_erfassen`.

What's going wrong? Thanks for your hints

```
 var fnstring = (interim_transcript).toLowerCase().replace(/ /gi, "_");

 console.log('fnstring:', fnstring)
 var fnstringCheck = fnstring.indexOf("diagnosen_erfassen") !== -1;
 console.log(fnstringCheck)

 switch (fnstring) {
    case (fnstring.indexOf("_arztbrief_analysieren") !== -1):
        $('.analyzesBtn').trigger('click');
        break;

    case (fnstring.indexOf("_einleitung_erfassen") !== -1):
        changeSection('einleitung', mergedSource);
        break;

    case (fnstring.indexOf("diagnosen_erfassen") !== -1):
         changeSection('einleitung', mergedSource);
         break;

        ...
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to take `true` in the [`switch` statement](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/switch), because the cases returns either `true` or `false`. The check uses a [Identity/strict equality operator `===`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Comparison_Operators#Identity).

```
var fnstring = (interim_transcript).toLowerCase().replace(/ /gi, "_");

console.log('fnstring:', fnstring)
var fnstringCheck = fnstring.indexOf("diagnosen_erfassen") !== -1;
console.log(fnstringCheck)

switch (true) { // strict comparison
    case fnstring.indexOf("_arztbrief_analysieren") !== -1:
        $('.analyzesBtn').trigger('click');
        break;

    case fnstring.indexOf("_einleitung_erfassen") !== -1:
        changeSection('einleitung', mergedSource);
        break;

    case fnstring.indexOf("diagnosen_erfassen") !== -1:
        changeSection('einleitung', mergedSource);
        break;
}
```

Comment: Cool, you save my day! Thx

Answer (score 1):

When you use switch statement, the expression in the switch is evaluated and compared to the values in the cases in order to decide which is the case statement that should be executed. See the documentation [here](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/switch).

In your case, the switch statement has a string expression, but your cases are evaluating to true or false, so none of them matches.

In my opinion, it would look more natural to express your logic with if-else checks:

```
if (fnstring.indexOf("_arztbrief_analysieren") !== -1) {
    $('.analyzesBtn').trigger('click');
} else if (fnstring.indexOf("_einleitung_erfassen") !== -1) {
    changeSection('einleitung', mergedSource);
} else if (fnstring.indexOf("diagnosen_erfassen") !== -1) {
    changeSection('einleitung', mergedSource);
}
```

Answer (score -1):

Switch case doesn't work like this. Parameter given to switch is used to compare with each case. In your case `switch` took a string param and all case is having boolean properties.

https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/switch